How to handle frequent CAPTCHA challenges in a Chinese app (Poizon) while testing on Nox emulator?
I’m testing an app called Poizon (a Chinese shopping app) on the Nox emulator. My goal is to parse and analyze data during testing, but the app frequently triggers CAPTCHA challenges, interrupting the process.
Setup:
Emulator: Nox App Player (Android 9)
Questions:

Are there best practices for reducing CAPTCHA prompts during app testing in emulators?

How can I ensure my emulator mimics a real device more accurately to avoid such triggers?

Are there tools or techniques for handling CAPTCHA challenges programmatically in this context?


Note: My intent is to facilitate testing and debugging only, not to bypass security measures in production.
not sure what to try
